# Why I get different result from serial port after this bitwise operation?

Tags: arduino, bitwise-operators, avr, atmel, avr-gcc

I am trying to learn AVR programming with Arduino. But there is an issue when ı try to activate the usart register bits.

```
UBRR0H = (BRC >> 8);
    UBRR0L = BRC;
    UCSR0B |= (1<<TXEN0);
    UCSR0C |= (1<<UCSZ01) | (1<<UCSZ01) ;
    while(1) //infinite loop
    {
        UDR0 = 'H';
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
```

When ı use | operator to activate TXEN and Some bit frames it activates and prints 'H' to my Serial port. That is the result that i want!

```
UCSR0B = (1<<TXEN0);
UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ01) | (1<<UCSZ01) ;
```

when ı use like this, I get 'È' to my serial port!

Why is that? What is the problem?

Comment: `UCSR0B |= (1<<TXEN0);` is `UCSR0B = UCSR0B | (1<<TXEN0)`, it is different from `UCSR0B = (1<<TXEN0);` (notice the missing | operation)?

Comment: Presumably, `UCSR0B` had some bits set, and you are clearing them by `UCSR0B = ...`.  Maybe have a look at the datasheed of that unknown device, so you know what value `UCSR0B` had after reset, same for `UCSR0C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ01) | (1<<UCSZ01);`

There might be 2 problems here:

- The statement above sets *one* bit in `UCSR0C`, notice that **`UCSZ01` is specified *twice***.  So this might be a typo, but even if not, it's confusing at least.
- We don't know which device you are using, so we have to guess here. Assuming it's something like ATmega48/88/168/328, **the reset status of `UCSR0C` is 0b00000110**, i.e. bits `UCSZ00` and `UCSZ01` are set!
    Thus `UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ01)` will set `UCSZ00` to zero, while `UCSR0C |= (1<<UCSZ01)` does not and `UCSZ00` will stay at its previous value.